# Explicit form of expectation of a function of sum of geometric Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $X^a$ and $X^b$ be geometric Brownian motions, i.e. for any $i\in \{a,b\}$,
$$
dX_t^i/X_t^i=\mu_idt+\sigma_idB^i_t
$$
with $X_0^i=x_i>0$, where $B^a$ and $B^b$ are independent Brownian motions. It is clear that $X_t^i=x_ie^{(\mu_i-\sigma_i^2/2)t+\sigma_iB^i_t}$ a.s. and $\mathbb{E}[X_t^i]=x_ie^{\mu_i t}$.

Question: Let $p\in(0,1)$, calculate $\mathbb{E}[(X_t^a+X_t^b)^p]$.

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[(X_t^a+X_t^b)^p]&=\mathbb{E}\left[(x_ae^{(\mu_a-\sigma_a^2/2)t+\sigma_aB^a_t}+x_be^{(\mu_b-\sigma_b^2/2)t+\sigma_bB^b_t})^p\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[(x_ae^{(\mu_a-\sigma_a^2/2)t+\sigma_a\sqrt{t}Z^a}+x_be^{(\mu_b-\sigma_b^2/2)t+\sigma_b\sqrt{t}Z^b})^p\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(x_ae^{(\mu_a-\sigma_a^2/2)t+\sigma_a\sqrt{t}u}+x_be^{(\mu_b-\sigma_b^2/2)t+\sigma_b\sqrt{t}v})^pf(du)f(dv)\right]
\end{align*}
where $Z^a$ and $Z^b$ are standard normal random variables and the function $f$ is the density of standard normal distribution. I tried to calculate this integral by tools such as Mathematica but none worked. Alternatively, one can try to solve the PDE from the martingale approach i.e. setting $E[(X_t^a+X_t^b)^p|\mathcal{F}_s]=:M_s$ and the PDE is yielded using Ito formula. However, PDE is hard to solve.

Comment: For general $p$ this looks difficult because $(X_t^a+X_t^b)^p$ is not lognormal. I would use a numeric integration or a Monte Carlo simulation.

Comment: Well I don't know if this helps but when $\sigma_a=\sigma_b=\sigma$ and by using Itô's multidimensional lemma on $f(x,y)=(x+y)^p$ applied to $x=X^a _t,y=X^b_t$ (if I didn't make miscalculations errors which is always a possibility with me), I find an interesting recurrence formula which is $E[Y_t^p]=\sigma^2.p.(p-1)\int_0^t E[Y_t^p].dt$ where $Y_t=X^a _t+X^b_t$